# MySQL query to count user orders by type

Tags: mysql

I have this 3 tables: users, orders and order_item.

When a user can have a order, and the order item can be event only, membership only or both, and so 2 line will be written to the order_items

users tables

```
id | user_id   | name  | phone
---|-----------|-------|------
1  | 123456789 | Jon   | 555-55555
2  | 123456780 | Alice | 555-6666
```

orders tables

```
id | user_id | user_uid  | user_info
---|---------|-----------|----------
1  | 1       | 123456789 | bla
2  | 2       | 123456780 | foo
3  | 2       | 123456780 | foo
```

order_items table

```
id  | order_id | order_type | price
--- | -------- | ---------- | ------
1   | 1        | membership | 70
2   | 1        | event      | 200
3   | 2        | event      | 300
4   | 3        | membership | 70
```

The relationship is like this,

```
order_items.order_id -> orders.id
orders.user_id -> users.id
orders.user_uid -> users.user_id
```

I'm looking for a query which will produce this type of output,

```
user_id   | name   | count_membership   | count_events   | total_orders
--------  | ------ | ------------------ | -------------- | --------------
123456789 | Jon    | 1                  | 1              | 1
123456780 | Alice  | 1                  | 1              | 2
```

I like to count the total orders a user have, and count how many of each of item he have. in the end I like to filter out all users where `count_membership = 0`

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your tables have *no* relations

Comment: What you seek is called *pivoting*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the expected result set by using some conditional aggregation

```
select u.user_id,
u.name,
sum(oi.membership_count) membership_count,
sum(oi.event_count) event_count,
count(o.id) total_orders
from users u
join orders o on u.id = o.user_id
join (
  select order_id,
  sum(order_type = 'membership') membership_count,
  sum(order_type = 'event') event_count
  from order_items 
  group by order_id
) oi on o.id = oi.order_id
group by u.user_id,u.name
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cebba6/3)

Answer (score 1):

Your query needs to join the three tables on their common fields, which would be user_id and order_id.

Since you said you don't want any results where membership is not an order type, your results example doesn't make sense and the grouping into single results that way using a single mysql query makes things complicated to put order_type which is a single field into two separate columns. So I adjusted slightly.

`select users.user_id, users.name, order_type, count(order_id) as total_orders from orders, order_items, users where users.user_id = orders.user_id and orders.id = order_items.order_id and order_type = "membership" group by users.user_id, users.name`

working output from mysql terminal:

`mysql> select users.user_id, users.name, order_type, count(order_id) as total_orders from orders, order_items, users where users.user_id = orders.user_id and orders.id = order_items.order_id and order_type = "membership" group by users.user_id, users.name;
+---------+------+------------+--------------+
| user_id | name | order_type | total_orders |
+---------+------+------------+--------------+
|     123 | Jon  | membership |            1 |
|    1234 | Pam  | membership |            2 |
+---------+------+------------+--------------+`